# ¿Por qué mi página no se hace responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive

Quiero hacer una página de mi sitio responsive pero no me deja. El header lo copie literalmente de otras páginas que si funciona el responsive pero al pegarla en otra no funciona. El body y el footer tampoco parece moverse. El archivo CSS esta linkeado y no estoy utilizando ningun tipo de grid o bootstrap. Las queries son @media screen and (min-width:320px) and (max-width:479px).

[image: El header, body y footer no me ocupan el 100%]

```
    <header class="nav-principalmultimedia">
    <nav class="nav-principal"> 
        <a href="../index.html" class="imagen-nav">
            <img src="../assets/images/Escuela-de-musica.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
        </a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="../pages/Quiénes-somos.html" class="li-principal">Nosotros</a></li>
            <li><a href="../pages/carreras.html" class="li-principal">Carreras</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="li-principal">Multimedia</a></li>
            <li><a href="../pages/solicitud-de-vacante.html" class="li-principal">Vacante</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
<main>
    <h1 class="Centrar">Videos e imágenes Nuestras</h1>
</main>
    <h2 class="Centrar especial prueba">Imágenes nuestras</h2>
    <div class="divimages">
        <img src="../assets/images/m-monk-E813FON0wDQ-unsplash.jpg" alt="nosotros" class="image1">
        <img src="../assets/images/wes-hicks-MEL-jJnm7RQ-unsplash.jpg" alt="nosotros" class="image1">
    </div>
    <div class="divimages">
        <img src="../assets/images/kevin-schmid-RV6-09J3HYU-unsplash.jpg" alt="nosotros" class="image1">
        <img src="../assets/images/paulette-wooten-FMiczIq8orU-unsplash.jpg" alt="nosotros" class="image1">
    </div>
    <section>
        <h2 class="Centrar">Entrevistas a Ex-alumnos</h2>
        <div class="divimages">
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mowd4qMRXkw" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen class="image2"></iframe>
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7QETmKoFzJI" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen class="image2"></iframe>
        </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: Hola, dónde estás incluyendo el CSS?

Comment: Para descartar cosas, en el head tienes algo así:  `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">` ????

Comment: Perdón por responder tarde, disculpa no entiendo lo del CSS. Mira, mando el link del sitio. Lo que estaria andando mal seria la página de multimedia y la de nosotros. https://agutusco.github.io/Pre-entrega3-Agustin-Lombardi.github.io/

Comment: la etiqueta meta que tengo son las siguientes:

`<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../assets/images/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css">
    <title>Multimedia</title>
</head>`